# Getting "command not found" while using cut on bash variable

Tags: bash, cut

I have two variables in a bash script

```
hostname="ab78ascsoadp003.abc.com"
Loc=`$hostname | cut -c3,4`
```

I am getting an error `ab78ascsoadp003.abc.com: command not found`

I am trying to use `cut command` so that `$Loc` gets `78`

Comment: `$hostname`'s content isn't a command, therefore it fails to be parsed as the first token of a pipeline.

Comment: you forgot the echo!

Answer (score 3):

While you can use `cut` to achieve this, sometimes it is useful to stick to [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
hostname="ab78ascsoadp003.abc.com"
Loc=${hostname:3:2}
```

> **`${parameter:offset:length}`**  Substring Expansion.  Expands to up to length characters of parameter starting at the character specified by offset.  If `length` is omitted, expands to the substring of parameter starting at the  character  specified  by `offset`.  `length` and `offset` are arithmetic expressions <snip>
>
> **<sub>source: `man bash`</sub>**

Answer (score 2):

```
hostname="ab78ascsoadp003.abc.com"
Loc=$(cut -c3,4 <<<"$hostname")
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing an `echo`

```
Loc=`echo $hostname | cut -c3,4`
```